# Make [pointer-to-member-functions] a synonym to [pointer-to-member]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [pointer-to-member-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-member-functions) is so rarely used that it has only 6 questions and no wiki. Looks like it was created in this question: [How to pass a member function as a parameter and execute list of methods on derived object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833379/how-to-pass-a-member-function-as-a-parameter-and-execute-list-of-methods-on-deri)

OTOH [pointer-to-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-member) has a lot more questions with a much more detailed wiki. IMHO [pointer-to-member-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-member-functions) should be made a synonym of this. Or should [pointer-to-member-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-member-functions) be removed?

Comment: Yeah, [pointer-to-member-functions] is unnecessary, removing it seems good. The 6 posts can be retagged, and the tag will get roombaed I think.

Comment: You know you've been successful when your product makes the jump from noun to verb.

Comment: We should handle [tag:member-function-pointers] at the same time. It has a poorer wiki than [tag:pointer-to-member], but 3X questions.

Comment: How is it that this question is not called “Pointing out that [pointer-to-member-functions] should be a member of [pointer-to-member]”??

Answer (score 4):

There are really three tags under consideration: [pointer-to-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-member), [pointer-to-member-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-member-functions), and [member-function-pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/member-function-pointers), all from C++.

According to the C++ standard (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#1.8)

> Pointers to data members and pointers to member functions are collectively called *pointer-to-member* types.

So all three tags are the same thing.

[pointer-to-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pointer-to-member) should be the main tag, and the other two can be synonyms for it.

Comment: Wrong.  https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#1.8  "Pointers to data members and pointers to member functions are collectively called pointer-to-member types"  And the main tag should follow the Standard verbiage.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've updated my response, including your link.

Comment: Pointer to data member and pointer to member function *are* distinct.  "Pointer to member" includes both.  I think you may have been using "pointer to member" only for data members.  The volume of questions isn't high enough to be worth having separate tags for pointers to data members and pointers to member functions... as well there are a number of topics that relate to both at the same time, such as how pointers to members work in the presence of virtual inheritance.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've looked but I can't find a tag for pointers to data members. Does it exist, and I'm not finding it? Questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503321) could do with that tag.

Comment: @cigien: Like I said, there aren't enough questions to be worth having separate tags for the two different kinds of pointer to member.  [tag:pointer-to-member] is perfect for that question.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ok, fair enough. A search for "pointers to data members" yields a lot of results, but I guess a lot of them would be FPs. I haven't looked in detail. The current answer makes the most sense then.